# Ordenação invertida SQL

Tags: sql

É possível efetuar uma ordenação dos códigos de um select de forma invertida?

Exemplo:

Como o último número do primeiro elemento é menor ele vem primeiro e para critério de desempate a segunda dezena será checada, assim como na ordenação normal, mas como informado, ao contrário.

1º = 58 `95` `52`

2º = 56 `84` `55`
...

Comment: Seria o ``ORDER BY coluna DESC`` que procura?

Comment: Robson, sua dúvida não está clara para mim. Você quer ordenar por partes de um número? Por gentileza, edite sua pergunta esclarecendo sua dúvida e colocando o que você gostaria que a consulta retorna-se.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você usar uma SUBSTR pegando apenas a ultima dezena e depois as centenas e depois milhares... Você poderia fazer a ordenação de cada uma e juntar no final.

```
SUBSTR(CODIGO, -2,1)
```

Comment: Consegui fazer assim mesmo, com a resposta do @Adriano Gomes, ele me deu a ideia de fazer assim.

Answer (score 4):

Sim, só usar a palavra reservada `desc`.

```
Select Coluna From Tabela
Order By Coluna Desc;
```

Comment: Não funciona, ele vai ordenar pelo 58 e 56.

Comment: Defina qual parâmetro deseja retornar em ordem decrescente. "Order By Coluna Desc;

Answer (score 1):

Se vc possui uma tabela que em cada linha armazena 3 dezenas, é só colocar os campos no order by, por exemplo:

```
SELECT d.dezena3, d.dezena2, d.dezena1 FROM dezena d
ORDER BY d.dezena3, d.dezena2, d.dezena1
```

Comment: O número está completo 589552 e 568455, apenas a ordenação que tem que ser separada, mas você me deu uma ideia